# How to save contour plot in ImageJ

Tags: contour, imagej

**ImageJ** has a nice contour plot plugin that might be downloaded from this link: http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/contour-plotter.html , it works fine and easily.
However, saving the image including the contour plot is not trivial, Using the save or save as options will save the image without the contour. It sound that the problem is in my understanding of how to merge the contour layer with the image layer.
I would be thankful if you can instruct me how to save the contour plot and the image in one file rather than taking a snapshot of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source contained in [Contour_Plotter.jar](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/download/jars/Contour_Plotter.jar), the contours are drawn directly onto the `Graphics` object of the parent `ImageCanvas`:

```java
private ImageCanvas Parent_Canvas;
private Graphics Parent_Graphics;

[...]

Parent_Graphics = Parent_Canvas.getGraphics();

[...]

Parent_Graphics.drawLine(
           (int)(Parent_Canvas.screenX((int)(pts[pt_right][X]+0.5))), 
           (int)(Parent_Canvas.screenY((int)(pts[pt_right][Y]+0.5))),
           (int)(Parent_Canvas.screenX((int)(pts[pt_at][X]+0.5))), 
           (int)(Parent_Canvas.screenY((int)(pts[pt_at][Y]+0.5))));
```

It seems that the plugin was written before ImageJ had introduced the concept of [`Overlay`s](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-11.html#sub:Overlay-Intro), and apparently it has not been maintained for a decade now. You can write to the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html) however and ask if the plugin is still maintained.

Unless you want to take a screenshot of the current image and save this, I would suggest you use a different approach using a sequence such as:

- set a threshold (*Image > Adjust > Threshold...*)
- convert it to a selection (*Edit > Selection > Create Selection*)
- draw the contour of the selection (*Edit > Draw*) or add it as a new overlay (*Image > Overlay > Add Selection...*)

You can automate this process for various intensity levels (i.e. threshold values) using the [macro recorder](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-31.html#sub:Record...), see also [this tutorial](http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Introduction_into_Macro_Programming).

Comment: Thanks ! From your answer I understand that there is no trivial way to save the file and the contour plot generated by this plugin. I would use IsoPhotContour2  plugin http://www.mecourse.com/landinig/software/software.html instead of the macro method you suggested.

Comment: I'll wait few days for other opinions before selecting this answer as the best one.

Comment: Oh yes, Gabriel Landini's plugin seems to be another very good option to achieve what you need.